# Error: class file needed by ValidDateOrNumericTypeHolder, need RegisterJodaTimeConversionHelpers() - its hopeless, I can't find the import

Tags: scala, mongodb, jodatime, casbah

maybe I'm blind or something but I can't find the import what I need. I'm playing with scala + mongodb. Everything is fine, I just have some problems with this JodaTimer. [In this tutorial](http://api.mongodb.org/scala/casbah/2.0/tutorial.html) you have to import it like this:

```
import com.mongodb.casbah.conversions.scala._
RegisterJodaTimeConversionHelpers()
```

Well, I can't find it. I just have:

```
import com.mongodb.casbah.commons._
import com.mongodb.casbah.util._
import com.mongodb.casbah.query._
//...
```

Well there is no "conversions". Is there another way to get this JodaTimer? Because without Joda you can't connect to the DB, you get the error-message:

```
    import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._

    object Main {
      def main(args: Array[String]) {

        val connection = MongoConnection() //error
        //val object1 = MongoDBObject("one" -> "hi","two" -> 42)
        //...
      }
    }

***1.) class file needed by ValidDateOrNumericTypeHolder is missing.***

***2.) reference value joda of package org refers to nonexisting symbol.***
```

Any ideas? Thank you

Edit:
If you read the [tutorial-site](http://api.mongodb.org/scala/casbah/2.0/setting_up.html)

```
**1.2.5. Casbah Modules:**

*...*

*Package: com.mongodb.casbah.commons*

*Dependencies: mongo-java-driver, scalaj-collection, scalaj-time, JodaTime, slf4j-api*

*...*
```

I have commons, but there is no JodaTime. I don't understand how to set up this jodatime. Do I need magic?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's an error in the docs. I'm using casbah 2.1.2 and I use the conversion like this (note the commons between casbah and conversions):

```
com.mongodb.casbah.commons.conversions.scala.RegisterJodaTimeConversionHelpers()
```

If you need JodaTime, I guess you must have a dependency on it yourself.

Comment: Hi. I tried now: com.mongodb.casbah.commons.conversions.scala.RegisterJodaTimeConversionHelpers() but i get the error "error: ';' expected but '(' found.
import com.mongodb.casbah.commons.conversions.scala.RegisterJodaTimeConversionHelpers()" or i can trie it do like on the casbah page: import com.mongodb.casbah.commons.conversions.scala._
RegisterJodaTimeConversionHelpers() but then i get the error "error: expected class or object definition
RegisterJodaTimeConversionHelpers()"

Comment: Could you provide a full sample?

Comment: With full sample I mean some (compilable) code having the problems you mentioned above. Then I could try it out very easily.

Comment: Hi. I have now com.mongodb.casbah.commons.conversions.scala.RegisterJodaTimeConversionHelpers()
 too or i can use import com.mongodb.casbah.util.bson.conversions._
RegisterJodaTimeConversionHelpers() but i get the errormessage: expected class or object definition
RegisterJodaTimeConversionHelpers() I posted the full code at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965028/error-expected-class-or-object-definition