# error: expected class or object definition

Tags: scala, mongodb

I have this (smart code):

```
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
import com.mongodb.casbah.util.bson.conversions._
RegisterJodaTimeConversionHelpers() //error

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val connection = MongoConnection()
  }
}
```

I get an error:

```
error: expected class or object definition
RegisterJodaTimeConversionHelpers()
```

I have to use this [`RegisterJodaTimeConversionHelpers()`](http://api.mongodb.org/scala/casbah/current/tutorial.html) (2.2. Briefly: Automatic Type Conversions), but there's always this error message. Any ideas?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You have to write this line of code somewhere it can be executed. How about in your `main` method instead?

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    RegisterJodaTimeConversionHelpers()
    val connection = MongoConnection()
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi. No this is not helping. If I copy that in the Main ill get the error:  class file needed by ValidDateOrNumericTypeHolder is missing. because there JodaTime wasnt registred.

Comment: It is not "because there JodaTime wasnt registred", it is because you are missing some dependencies on your classpath.