# 'wrong top statement declaration' when using slick in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, intellij-scala

I'm currently porting a project from scala 2.9 to 2.10, therefore I have to use slick instead of scalaquery. I'm using slick 2.1.0 for now since it supports MS Access.

According to [this tutorial](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/2.1.0/schemas.html#mapped-tables) and the [upgrade guide](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/2.1.0/upgrade.html) I changed `Robs` from object to class and added the val `robs`:

[image: Error defining val robs]

Why do I get the error message `Wrong top statement declaration` and how do I get rid of it?

EDIT: I'm new to scala... According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965028/error-expected-class-or-object-definition) it seems like I can't put a val outside of methods or classes, right? The code above is directly in a packge. But what is the right approach for slick then? Should I move the code in some class or trait?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/2.1.0/schemas.html#table-query) I changed

`val robs = TableQuery[Robs]`

to

`object robs extends TableQuery(new Robs(_)) {}`.

No warnings or errors anymore. :)